# Aligning Kartik Sidenav

Tags: yii, widget

I can see Kartik Sidenav in my home page. Now I want the sideNav to continue till the bottom of the page. 
And the main content be in the right of the sideNav not behind it. Also SideNav is supposed to be collapsible. 
I can't see it. Please help. I'm attaching how my pages look like.
[image: Home Page]
[image: Any Page]

My backend/views/layout/main.php is as below

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use common\widgets\Alert;
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
use yii\helpers\Url;


AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
<?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
];
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
} else {
    $menuItems[] = [
        'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
    ];
}
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();
?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">


<?php
 echo SideNav::widget([      

'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
'heading' => 'Operations',


'items' => [
    [
        'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'label' => 'Home',
        'icon' => 'home',
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=tc/bills',
        'label' => 'Insert TC',
        'icon' => 'cloud',
    ],

    [
        'label' => 'Help',
        'icon' => 'question-sign',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
        ],
    ],
],

 ]);  
?>
</div>       
</div>

<div class="container">
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>

</div>


<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company <?= date('Y') ?></p>

    <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
</div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the SideNav in the left column you must organiza you page proper inside the container.

Essentially move your SideNav  `<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">`
 inside the `<div class="container">`

and place the  $content inside a remaining column

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
```

this way ..

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use common\widgets\Alert;
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
use yii\helpers\Url;


AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
<?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
];
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
} else {
    $menuItems[] = [
        'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
    ];
}
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();
?>


<div class="container">
      <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">


  <?php
   echo SideNav::widget([      

  'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
  'heading' => 'Operations',


  'items' => [
      [
          'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
          'label' => 'Home',
          'icon' => 'home',
      ],
      [
          'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=tc/bills',
          'label' => 'Insert TC',
          'icon' => 'cloud',
      ],

      [
          'label' => 'Help',
          'icon' => 'question-sign',
          'items' => [
              ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
              ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
          ],
      ],
  ],

   ]);  
  ?>   
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
    <?= $content ?>
</div>

</div>
```

If you need a wide container you can simply change the class `container` this way  `<div class="container-fluid">`

for reduce the left spacing of the SideNav you can set an in tag styling for the div containing the SideNav

```
 `<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-3" style="padding-left: 0px;">
```

`

Comment: Works like a charm. Still there is some space in the left of the sidenav. Can you tell me how can sidenave to the extreme left of the screen?

Comment: I have already posted  .. if you want use all the screen wide set container class = "container-fluid"

Comment: yes I've used that. Still some space is there at the extreme left.

Comment: How many pixel do you have at the extreme left with container-fluid ?  and how much you want for your styling ?.. (use browser inspector for obtain the left spacing)

Comment: In the inspect element I can see padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; I'm not sure if this information you need or any thing else. I'm using firefox and the same is happening with chrome as well.

Comment: there is 30px gap at the left

Comment: That is really helpful. I've added this in both the div classes. But still I have 15px left in the extreme left and sideNav and 15px between sidenav and the content. Thanks for helping. Can you please tell me if this spacing also can be removed.

Comment: Try setting padding-right:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;

Comment: 15px will not be any problem for now. Leave that for now. Many many thanks for your support.